# What is the replacement for hasRequired with EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

With Entity Framework we had `HasRequired` on a field. What is the alternative replacement for that with EF core?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

I tried with `HasRequired` but it throws error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out the [Required and Optional Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#required-and-optional-relationships) in the EF Core Documentation.

Specifically I think you'll want something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Relationship)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

Or something like that - you haven't given much information to go on

Comment: IsRequired doesn't appear to be part of EF 2.0

Comment: They still seem to use it in their code base: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.0/src/EFCore.Relational.Specification.Tests/Query/NullSemanticsQueryRelationalFixture.cs#L19

Comment: I don't think `HasOne()` works with `IsRequired`. Been stewing over this for a while and it appears `IsRequird` only works on `ReferenceCollectionBuilder` whereas `HasOne` is a `ReferenceNavigationBuilder`. I could be wrong, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: `.Property(p => p.Relationship).IsRequired` would seem to be the correct call.