# c# modelBuilder.Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have these lines of code in the DBcontext class. Can someone explain to me what it does? Does it populate User_roles? But if it does should not it be already inside public DbSet<User_Role> User_Roles.  Or does it populate nav properties of Role and user?

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User_Role>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Role)
            .WithMany(y => y.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User_Role>()
           .HasOne(x => x.User)
           .WithMany(y => y.UserRoles)
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    }
```

User class

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

    //nav propery
    public List<User_Role> UserRoles { get; set; }

}
```

Role class

```
public class Role
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //nav property
    public List<User_Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

User_role class

```
public class User_Role
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Entity has a mapping file that maps the database tables/fields to the c# classes which is an EDMX file in the project.  The code posted creates the model from the classes.  You can build a model either from classes or from database.

Comment: @jdweng you got it half right, as usual. You can see by `HasOne()` ([as opposed to `HasRequired()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577357/what-is-the-replacement-for-hasrequired-with-ef-core)) that they're using Entity Framework core, which [doesn't have the notion of EDMX mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx). The fluent mapping always has been distinct from EDMX anyway, it's one or the other.

Comment: Sorry @jdweng, but half right is stated too friendly. Please think twice before posting utterly confusing comments. Even if this was EF6 (classic) this would be code-first so all but EDMX.

Comment: @modestas, please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't populate anything in terms of data, assuming that's what you're asking. All that does is configure one-to-many relationships between `User_Role` and `Role`, and `User_Role` and `User`. This will create your FK constraints in the database when you run migrations and configures your navigation properties.

Recommended reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key